# Find non null columns | bash

Tags: text-processing

I have a feed in hdfs.

I have to find the the rows which has the 3rd column as not null.

The feed is separated by the delimter `|`

SQL Equivalent

```
select * from feed_table where column_3 is not null;
```

Input:

```
1|abc|123
2|def|
3|ff|124
4|gh|
```

Output: Here the 3rd column is not null.

```
1|abc|123
3|ff|124
```

Comment: Is the data in a file? How are the columns delimited?  Bash isn't a great text processing tool; there's probably a better way/tool.  Showing some example input & output would get you a better answer.

Comment: @JeffSchaller I have updated the question.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use `awk` for this task. Set the delimiter in awk to `|` and then check if the 3rd column is not an empty string.

```
$ cat /tmp/foo 
1|abc|123
2|def|
3|ff|124
4|gh|
$ awk -F'|' '$3 != ""' /tmp/foo
1|abc|123
3|ff|124
```

Comment: or, in code golf, `awk -F'|' '$3' input`

Answer (score 4):

Two `grep` options:

```
grep -v '|$' < input
```

The above looks for lines that *don't* end with a pipe. If your data file has *only* three columns, then this is a short-cut for finding (excluding) lines that don't have any data after the last (second) pipe.

```
grep '|[^|].*|.' < input
```

The above is a little bit more strict; it requires the presence of a pipe symbol, followed by anything except a pipe symbol (`[^|]`), followed by anything, followed by a pipe symbol, followed by *something* (`.`). This would allow for an empty *first* field.